# Best way to subtract certain hours from timestamp records in mysql using mysql client

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysql-5.6

Context:
Mysql 5.6

Can someone suggest all/some(if not all) the possible ways to do the same using mysql client?

Answer (score 1):

For a column of type timestamp, you can use **Interval** for adding certain hours, mins etc.

**For example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestamp_col BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
                        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

You can read more about [mysql interval](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/)